# Add autosuggest to TagsInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

To write the site, I use JavaScript, the React framework, and the library mui.

On my site, one of the input fields for the user is done using TagsInput. Thus, the user can enter data, press enter, see the tag, and optionally delete it.

For TagsInput, I did not use libraries, but wrote the code myself. It will be presented below.

I would like to improve the functionality for the user and add a predictive search (autofill). That is, when the user begins to enter letters (let it be, for example, car brands), if the car brand is currently in the database (not to complicate things, you can make a regular list or other convenient type of data), the user will be offered options for autofill.

For example: the user clicks on the field for entering a tag and enters the first letter "A" and prompts are given to him - Alfa Romeo, Aston Martin. If the Audi is not currently in the database, then the Audi tooltip will not pop up.

I will be glad for any help.

FilterMarkAuto.jsx

```
export default function FilterMarkAuto({ isExpanded, setIsExpanded }){
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

return (
    <ArrowDropdown
        isExpanded={isExpanded}
        setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
        title="Name car"
        onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}>
            
        {isExpanded && 
            <TagsInput tags={values} 
                       setTags={setValues} 
                       inputPlaceholder="Enter a car" />}
    </ArrowDropdown>
);
}
```

TagsInput.jsx

```
export default function TagsInput(props) {
    const tags = props.tags
    const setTags = props.setTags
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState('');
    const [isKeyReleased, setIsKeyReleased] = React.useState(false);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setInput(value);
    };

    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
        const { key } = e;
        const trimmedInput = input.trim();

        if ((key === ',' || key === 'Enter') && trimmedInput.length && !tags.includes(trimmedInput)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTags(prevState => [...prevState, trimmedInput]);
            setInput('');
        }

        if (key === "Backspace" && !input.length && tags.length && isKeyReleased) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const tagsCopy = [...tags];
            const poppedTag = tagsCopy.pop();

            setTags(tagsCopy);
            setInput(poppedTag);
            setIsKeyReleased(false);
        }

    };

    const onKeyUp = () => {
        setIsKeyReleased(true);
    }

    const deleteTag = (index) => {
        setTags(prevState => prevState.filter((tag, i) => i !== index))
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.container}>
            {tags.map((tag, index) => <div className={classes.tag}>
                <ClearIcon className={classes.del} fontSize="big" onClick={() => deleteTag(index)} />
                {tag}
            </div>
            )}
            <input
                className={classes.input}
                value={input}
                placeholder={props.inputPlaceholder}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div>);
}
```

Comment: Missing `classes` for `TagsInput`. Please add that you your question. I'd also like to have some a file that show the basic usage of this code. - where does `FilterMarkAuto` get `expanded` , what does `value` contain? It's is generally a very good idea to share some kind of [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that our time isn't wasted on making the base code work first before getting to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do it like google autoComplete or do you want text to appear in the background and when someone press a arrow it fills up? Also, if you can get the Minimal Reproducible Example this would be easier

Comment: @innocent I'm trying to do the following: when the user clicks on the input field (where it says "Enter a car") and starts typing the first letter of the car, then the autocomplete will show what car options the user can currently select to make a tag.

Thus, if the user typed the letter "A", what would autocomplete tell him what cars are beginning with the letter "A"

Comment: @innocent Thus, so that the user does not enter the entire name of the car, but can click on the hint, and the brand of the car appears in the tag

Comment: @Swiffy I added what you asked

Comment: @Павел I think you linked an old version of the sandbox? For example, the TagsInput.js is totally empty.

Comment: @Swiffy Check now

Comment: @Павел Good work! Always include a small demo if possible, it makes questions so much more easier and more attractive to try and solve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-albattani-kn1yfr

I added the following tags as suggestions:

```
const tagSuggestions = [
    "Audi",
    "Mercedes Benz",
    "Renault",
    "Ford",
    "Ferrari"
]
```

There isn't much to it, this is the part that renders the suggestions:

```
{suggestedTags.length > 0 && (
    <div className={classes.tagSuggestionWrapper}>
        {suggestedTags.map((t) => {
            return (<div key={t} className={classes.tagSuggestion} onClick={() => { selectTag(t) }}>{t}</div>);
        })}
    </div>
)}
```

And then there's the tag selection from suggestions:

```
const selectTag = (tag) => {
    setTags((prevState) => [...prevState, tag]);
    setSuggestedTags([]);
    setInput("");
}
```

And the search of the suggestions based on what has been typed:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setInput(value);

    if(value.length < 2) return;

    const matchedSuggestions = tagSuggestions.filter((s) => {
        return s.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
    setSuggestedTags(matchedSuggestions);
};
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you very much!
There is only one caveat.
In my code, it was provided that one tag cannot be entered more than once, but now this rule is violated. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: so I would like to do this: if any car brand is already in the tag, so that it does not get into the search

Comment: You just add something like `&& !tags.includes(s);` to this part `return s.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) > -1`.

Comment: You probably should also save all tags to `tags` in lower case form so that won't cause you issues

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how to fix a small problem: if I start typing text in the input field, I start to be prompted with options. Everything is great here! But if I delete all the entered letters, then the proposed options remain. Tell me how to remove the hints after deleting the text?

Comment: `if(value.length < 2) { setSuggestedTags([]); return; }`

Comment: I've already pretty much worked with your code, but I still can't figure out what to add the code to, in case there are no suitable car brands, display an inscription about it. If you don't mind, let me know.

Comment: Hello. Here again I had to return to your answer and code. And I would like to ask you. At the moment, the proposed options can only be selected with the mouse cursor and by clicking the left mouse button on the appropriate option.
Is it possible to make it so that the proposed options can be selected using the up-down keys and the enter key (while retaining the possibility of the previous functionality). That is, the scheme is as follows: the user enters characters and navigates through the proposed options using the up and down keys and selects a tag using the enter key.